# Javascript variable as expression gives unexpected identifier error

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have java script code for filter an array based on some value.

In this I am assigning one line of code  `_(obj.boardingPoints).map('location').intersection(json[0]).value().length > 0`  to  a variable named `st`

```
var st='_(obj.boardingPoints).map('location').intersection("'+json[0]+'").value().length > 0'
```

And replaced variable `st` in the code for filtering array

```
var tresult = _.filter(result, function(obj) {
                    return 
                        st||_(obj.droppingPoints).map('location').intersection(dpLocations).value().length > 0
                        || _.includes(busTypes, obj.busType)
                        || _.includes(operatorNames, obj.operatorName);
                      });
```

But it will throw an unexpected identifier error in this line

`var st='_(obj.boardingPoints).map('location').intersection("'+json[0]+'").value().length > 0`'

Comment: I think that in your code return will get semicolon inserted, so the filter function will return undefined which is falsy so the filter will return empty array.

Comment: what does your json[] look like?

Comment: @ben `json[]` of gives array of parameters.It will gives correct output

Comment: @jcubic filtering  returns the whole input array.

Comment: Of course the filter always returns the whole input array.  In the filter, if you return false, the item of the input array is not returned and the item is returned if anything other than false is returned.  Your variable 'st' is really a string.  that filter will never return false.  That's why you're getting the whole input array.  The structure of the json[ ] really matters.  That's why I was asking what it looks like.

Comment: Each `json[i]` is an array of items  here is console of `json` `[Array[1],Array[2]]`

Answer (score 2):

Ok, from your responses in the comments.  I think I have enough info to write the answer assuming that json[i] is an array of strings:

```
var tresult = _.filter(result, function(obj) {
    return _(obj.boardingPoints).map('location').intersection(json[i]).value().length > 0
        || _(obj.droppingPoints).map('location').intersection(dpLocations).value().length > 0
        || _.includes(busTypes, obj.busType)
        || _.includes(operatorNames, obj.operatorName);
});
```

You can assign the expression to a variable but I think there isn't any real benefit in this case.  However, if you really insist on assigning the expression to a variable, leave it as an expression, convert it to a string would not work. Here is the code where the 1st expression is assigned to a variable:

```
var tresult = _.filter(result, function(obj) {
    var st = _(obj.boardingPoints).map('location').intersection(json[i]).value().length > 0;

    return
        st || _(obj.droppingPoints).map('location').intersection(dpLocations).value().length > 0
        || _.includes(busTypes, obj.busType)
        || _.includes(operatorNames, obj.operatorName);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at syntax highlighting you're trying to use single quote inside single quote. Try this:

```
var st='_(obj.boardingPoints).map("location").intersection("'+json[0]+'").value().length > 0'
```